# Email Id and text parsing in R

Tags: r, email, parsing

I am getting some 55k mails each month & I have taken up an assignment to analyse the mails.  While the .eml has lot of content, I am typically interested in email text content as follows:

```
From: "SavReader" <info@savreader.com>
To: <pgmagesh@gmail.com>
Subject: Export file SavReader.com
Date: Mon, 2 Nov 2015 08:37:52 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0000_01D11549.C39BD260"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0000_01D11549.C39BD260
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello from SavReader!

The file that you submitted for export is now available for download
from SavReader - all files will be stored for 1 day from receipt of
this mail.

Download file <http://www.savreader.com/export/qlysDuv1xQ.xls> 

Thanks, 

Team SavReader

------=_NextPart_000_0000_01D11549.C39BD260
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello from SavReader!<br><br>The file that you submitted for export is now available for download from SavReader - all files will be stored for 1 day from receipt of this mail.<br><br><a href=http://www.savreader.com/export/qlysDuv1xQ.xls>Download file</a><br><br>Thanks, <br><br>Team SavReader
------=_NextPart_000_0000_01D11549.C39BD260--
```

I am interested in extracting Subject:, From:, and the content of the mail.  While the body of the mail is extracted in both `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` as well as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` I figured I get matching pair of delimit strings `--001a113d7c1e5de339051fdaaf69` before and after `--001a113d7c1e5de339051fdaaf69--` (the closing delimiter ends with additional two "--") the message or the body of the mail is sandwiched between these uids.   I was trying to parse the email id and content of the mail.  I have used the following code, where a is the name of my .eml file:

```
pat = '([From]): ([a-zA-Z]) (([a-z0-9_\\.-]+)@([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6}))'
d <- str_match(pattern = pat, a)
d
```

another option:

```
strsplit(gsub("(?s)^_+\\s+", "", a, perl=T) , "_+\\s*(?=From:)", perl=T)[[1]]
```

another option:

```
d <- str_extract(string=a,pattern="From:\\b[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\@[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\.[A-Za-z]+")
```

and many other options given in SO.  What I want to extract is:

```
From: DEFHIJ <abc@xyz.in>
```

and the html content of the mail between the matching delimiter strings.  Can someone help pls?

Comment: You seem to assume that mail has a predetermined number of MIME body parts in a particular order, but that is generally not true.  There could be zero MIME parts (for a pre-MIME message; then the body is implicitly content-type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii" and content-transfer-encoding: 7bit) or an arbitrary number of arbitrary MIME types in arbitrary order.  Of course, if you *know* that all your messages come from a single client or organization which can be trusted to always produce the same MIME structure, that's still a valid assumption.

Comment: You should also cope with `From: (newline)(space)=?us-ascii?B?bW9vCg==?= <moo@example.com>` and `FROM:moo@example.com (no real name!)` and other shenanigans.  This is a nontrivial problem, even for full-time professionals.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee for the clarification....I too noticed the inconsistency....my client serves me both text/plain and within the same mail i get the html output.  However the boundary delimiter is consistent with the html and not with the plain text.  Hence I thought it would be easier to use html

Comment: @tripleee I have checked various mails...the boundary tags for html is always consistent......

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "boundary tags for HTML".  The MIME boundary is defined in the header and separates each body part; like you correctly concur, the final closing separator has two dashes at the end to mark it as final.  What you find between the boundary separators can be any type; that's why there are type tags to identify the type, after all.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the *sender*, not your mail server, decides which MIME parts there are.

Comment: Yes...I meant the MIME boundary only...have not worked with emails before...hence not sure about the terminologies....but I am still wondering if we could parse the content between the MIME boundary by adding a condition the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with R to tell you how to do that, but it shouldn't be hard.  Pull the boundary out of the headers, split the body on the boundary, look for a part with the MIME headers you want (i.e. Content-Type: text/html) but maybe prepare to fall back to a secondary type if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94420/discussion-between-anonymous-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to include angular brackets and also match the space which exist between `From:` and the first letter using `\\s*`.

```
str_extract(string=a,pattern="^From:\\s*[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\s*<[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+@[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\.[A-Za-z]+>")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hZ1fK9/1)

or

```
str_extract(a, "^From:.*")
```

Comment: Many thanks Avinash, the first option did not work, but the second one did.  Any idea how do I extract the html body of the mail...it is available between those two delimiters.

Comment: try `"<div\\b[\\s\\S]*</div>"`

Comment: returns NA's, for every line of the data